# Why does the first Joda DateTime instance gets a non-UTC Chronology?

Tags: timezone, equals, jodatime, utc

`date1` and `date2` are not equal here because of the different Chronologies:

```
val formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis
val date1 = formatter.parseDateTime("2012-01-03T00:00:00Z")
val date2 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 3, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC)
println(date1.getChronology) // ISOChronology[Europe/Bucharest]
println(date2.getChronology) // ISOChronology[UTC]
assert(date1 === date2)      // fails
```

Here they're equal though:

```
val formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.dateTimeNoMillis
val date1 = formatter.withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC).parseDateTime("2012-01-03T00:00:00Z")
val date2 = new DateTime(2012, 1, 3, 0, 0, DateTimeZone.UTC)
println(date1.getChronology) // ISOChronology[UTC]
println(date2.getChronology) // ISOChronology[UTC]
assert(date1 === date2)      // succeeds
```

I know `DateTime` instances should have same Chronologies in order to be treated as equal, but I would have expected that the Z designator in the string would make the formatter parse `date1` in the UTC Chronology. I'm pretty sure I'm confused on the difference between `Chronology` and `DateTimeZone`, so I'd really appreciate if someone can point it out what exactly is that I'm conflating.

BTW, the code is in Scala and the assertions are from ScalaTest, but this shouldn't make any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parsing will create a date-time in the default time-zone unless it is further configured. The "Z" is taken into account, but the time-of-day is then adjusted as necessary to match your time-zone (Bucharest).

```
val date1 = formatter.withOffsetParsed().parseDateTime("2012-01-03T00:00:00Z")
```

Add `withOffsetParsed()` to get the behaviour you  want.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I get it now, but IMHO the API is a bit counter-intuitive. The timezone designator is mandatory for parsing but actually ignored when the transformation to a `DateTime` object is done. What's the rationale?

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan: The timezone is not ignored at all, it's used to compute the precise point in the (universal) time, and then a DateTime is constructed corresponding to that instant of time in your current timezone.

Comment: Try adding to you first example `assert(date1.getMillis() == date2.getMillis())`to verify that they correspond to the same "physical" instant of time.

Comment: @leonbloy indeed, I understand they represent the same instant in time. What I don't understand is why it's using my local timezone when the string explicitly says UTC. That's what the Z is for, right? And the name of the method that fixes this behaviours, `withOffsetParsed`, sounds as if the timezone offset is never parsed without that explicit call.